# Connect to an Oracle database with a VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm working on a VB.NET application which has a function where it's connected to an Oracle database and gather data through different queries.

The program works fine. My question is that is it possible to operate such an application without ODBC, Oracle Instant Client or TNSNames.ora?

It's needed to run on possibly 50+ machines and it would be a real pain in the ... to install these drivers/software to each computer.
This is my first windows application ever, before I only use Java for my projects. So I'm very unfamiliar with it.

I read something about that I need to reference the corresponding dll files in my .NET project so the end user don't need to worry about any other program beside the main one.
If it's true, can someone tell me what are the required dll files and where to get them? I tried to use the dll files from ODTwithODAC installion but Visual Studio doesn't let me reference them.

P.S: Go easy on me, English isn't my native language.

Comment: Download and install Oracle ODP. NET **Managed Driver**. With this you have to copy just a single dll along your exe file.

Comment: Wow! I did not know it will be this easy. :D Thank you very much sir. Everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

ODP.Net Managed Driver, and don't forget to set copyLocal=true in the reference properties or the reference might not get copied after you publish and install the application on another computer.